# how to determine year, month, day ordering based on locale?

Tags: javascript, date, internationalization

I would like to display three custom dropdowns for the user to select year, month, and day of their identification card.

How can I determine which order to show the year, month, and day, using only JavaScript (not `moment`)?

Example output for `en-US`:

```
['month', 'day', 'year']
```

Example output for `en-CA`:

```
['year', 'month', 'day']
```

Comment: Far better to use an unambiguous format, e.g using the short month name. People in a particular locality don’t always use the same Oder of values, e.g. some places might use “January 21, 2018” as a formal date (such as British newspapers), but 21/1/2018 for short.

Comment: @RobG I am using a short month name. The point of the question was to determine in which order to show the year, month, and day dropdown menus. The month dropdown menu contains short month names.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function datePartOrder(locale) {
  const parts = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale).formatToParts();
  const filteredParts = parts.filter(part => ['year', 'month', 'day'].includes(part.type));
  const filteredPartNames = filteredParts.map(part => part.type);
  return filteredPartNames;
}

// examples:

console.log(datePartOrder('en-US')); //["month", "day", "year"] );
console.log(datePartOrder('en-CA')); //["year", "month", "day"]
```

Comment: Cool, but how does the OP know which language tag to use? For me, omitting the language generates the wrong sequence in some browsers (i.e. it's not consistent with my system settings).